# Is it possible to have multiple lines in the overset with proper font size?

Tags: math-mode, overset

I'm trying to have multiple lines in the overset but what I could get till now with aligned environment is the wrong the font size. Nestig doesn't give much better resullts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x \overset{x = y, y = z}&{=} z
&
x \overset{\begin{gathered}x = y,\\ y = z\end{gathered}}&{=} z
&
x \overset{\overset{x = y,}{y = z}}&{=} z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get this properly ?

---

**Update!**
I could get the fontsize but the now is there a way to control the alignment ? (Sorry for changing the question a little)

The code is `x \overset{x = y}{\overset{y = z}{=}} z`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to use `\substack`, perhaps?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x \overset{\substack{x = y \\ y = z}}&= z \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Aligning at the equals signs in the overset part doesn't seem like a good idea.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alignedsubstack}[1]{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{\sf@size}{0}\selectfont
    \thickmuskip=0mu \medmuskip=0mu
    $\begin{aligned}[b]#1\end{aligned}$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x \overset{\alignedsubstack{x &= \sin y \\ \sin y &= z}}&{=} z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to control the alignment of the line within this, as in the aligned environment ?

Comment: @Physor What alignment are you thinking to? This will center the lines with respect to one another.

Comment: to align the equality signs of all line vertically, in general case, i.e. you have instead of x=y and y=z, you have x=sin y and sin y=z.

Comment: @Physor Why should you want that? I'd never do it that way, as it gives very unbalanced output.

Comment: I'll accept your answer later if noone suggests somthing better. Thanks

Comment: @Physor I added the code, but it really isn't a good idea.